# .NET MAUI - Add singleton of interface, instantiate later with specific implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-maui

I have a .NET MAUI app that is capable of connecting to different backends. The type of backend is represented by a specific implementation of a generic "IBackendConnection" interface. Something like:

```
public interface IBackendConnection
{
    public void TalkToBackend();
}
public class BackendType1 : IBackendConnection
{
    public void TalkToBackend()
    { /* do something */ }
}
public class BackendType2 : IBackendConnection
{
    public void TalkToBackend()
    { /* do something else */ }
}
```

So anywhere in the app I can simply inject `IBackendConnection backend` and do

```
backend.TalkToBackend();
```

Some time during runtime of the app the user will chose a specific backend, at which time I would like to instantiate the singleton with the corresponding implementation.
So, the question is, is it possible to "late instantiate" a singleton in this way or do I need to go look for another solution since a singleton is not appropriate for this use case?

I am not concerned about swapping one backend for another during the runtime of the app, since I can just close and reopen the app in case the backend needs to be changed.

Thank you,

Joerg.

Comment: "Some time during runtime of the app the user will chose a specific backend, at which time I would like to instantiate the singleton with the corresponding implementation" <-- This is not how singletons work....

Comment: Let me ask you, what _exactly_ do you think the term "singleton" means?

Comment: @Dai, I would say it is a pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance throughout the lifetime of the app run. I only ever need a single backend connection at the same time for this use case, but to which API to talk to is not decided until later on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if what you are asking is possible, but my suggestion to get around your issue is to implement a factory interface.

```
public interface IBackendConnectionFactory
{
    public IBackendConnection GetBackend(BackendEnum backendEnum)
{
```

Then create a concreate class that can be registered.

```
public class BackendConnectionFactory : IBackendConnectionFactory
{
    //constructor injection and backing fields
    
    public IBackendConnection GetBackend(BackendEnum backendEnum)
    {
        switch(backendEnum)
        {
            case backend1:
                return new BackendConnection1()
        }
        // and so on...
    {
}
```

I know you said you were not concerned about changing the backend during run time, but this pattern would allow you the possibility to change the backend as you need without restarting the app.

Comment: Is there a reason why `BackendConnectionFactory` gets its own interface `IBackendConnectionFactory`? I'm not convinced it adds any value in this case, as usually "root" factories (especially those used for bootstrapping) are accessed directly through their concerete-types.

Comment: Also, `interface` types members don't have access modifiers (like `public`) unless they're default-implementations (C# 8.0), so as-it-is your code won't compile.

Comment: Based on your answer and @Dai 's comments, does this look sensible enough? [link](https://gist.github.com/jaldinger/05ce3b4b5ea2836df8a62caa53b906b1)

Comment: My only thought is why are you saving the current backend type and also returning the backend type?  Without seeing the rest of your code, I would argue just return the backend based on the switch.  No need for this: 
`if (backend is not BackendType1) backend = new BackendType1(httpClientFactory);`

Comment: Well, I do need to instantiate a certain type sometime. But you are right, it doesn't make much sense to do it at the moment I require it. I need to do it at the moment I can decide which backend connection to use. So I added another method to choose the backend type and now do the instantiation there: [updated link](https://gist.github.com/jaldinger/05ce3b4b5ea2836df8a62caa53b906b1)

Comment: You are correct, you do need to create the object at some point, but I believe you should just return a new instance of the backend that is required each time rather than trying to save the last used instance and reusing it. This is just my thought based on the code I have seen. Nonetheless, your code would still do as you require.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I need to instantiate only once is that each API maintains certain information such as authentication information after the first login is accomplished. This session information is then reused in subsequent calls in order to avoid additional HTTP requests. That is also the reason I inject an IHttpClientFactory into each one, so that each endpoint can have a single instance of HTTPClient in the end. Thanks for your thoughts and input! Did you want to make any update to your answer before I accept it?

Comment: You are welcome.  No update to answer.  Might I suggest looking into named clients for your HTTP requests?  You can set up all that information in startup so it doesn't need to be maintained in the class. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients)